# solve system equation $\sin(x) – \sin(2y) = 2y−x $, $ \cos(x) + 5\sin(y) = 4 $

Tags: trigonometry

Can you tell me how to solve this system equation ?

$$ \sin(x) – \sin(2y) = 2y−x $$
$$ \cos(x) + 5\sin(y) = 4 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** From the first equation, we have $x+\sin x=2y+\sin2y$, implying that $x=2y$, since the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,~f(t)=t+\sin t$ is bijective.